# Queries on Spring LDAP user authentication with PoolingContextSource

Tags: spring, ldap, pooling

I have few queries on Spring LDAP user authentication.

1. Any custom/predefined way to authenticate a user(both using username and password) by using spring LDAP pooling(Not JNDI pool but PoolingContextSource of Spring LDAP).
2. Pooling supports search method where we can get the password in the attributes but the for password is an object. Any way we can get back the original SSHA format of the password.
   With that it will be easy to extract the salt and encode the password recieved from UI and then compare and authenticate using LdapShaPasswordEncoder.